# How to Deploy a React App(code present on github) to Azure WebApp using jenkins and TerraForm

Tags: azure, jenkins-pipeline, azure-web-app-service, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I basically want to deploy(CICD) a React App(simple create-react-app) present in GitHub to Azure Webapp using Jenkins and TerraForm. I am in search of step by step process to do this.
I can't use the Azure DevOps platform since it is restricted in the organization I work.

Comment: Do you have any concerns about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial for [Deploy to Azure App Service with Jenkins and the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/deploy-to-azure-app-service-using-azure-cli) might help.

But considering your React App already present in GitHub, there is a easier choice to deploy, which is using Git Action.

1. Create an App Service on portal.
2. Navigate to Deployment Center, better to use the Preview version.
3. Configure the CI/CD:
   [image]
4. Go to your GitHub and see the Action logs, which is more clear than portal:
   [image]